# Getting a long error while migrating using cmd to 'XAMPP' for database connection

Tags: python, django, xampp

Getting an error while using ->python manage.py migrate

firstline216:in ensure_connection self.connect()

lastline-> access denied for user'root'@localhost,

Comment: DATABASES =  {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'djangoproject', 
        'USER': 'root', 
        'PASSWORD': '12345678', 
        'HOST': 'localhost', 
        'PORT': '', 
               }
             }

Comment: So far, your problem is totally unclear. Consider providing more elaborated details, code and scenario.

Comment: Please provide a complete stack trace and any relevant code snippets

Comment: While working in Django project , I am connecting to mysql database using XAMPP .So i changed the settings.py (using Sublime Text3 editor)                  
  from default sqllite to mysql as shown below :    
DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'NAME': 'djangoproject', 'USER': 'root', 'PASSWORD': '12345678', 'HOST': 'localhost', 'PORT': '', } }                                                                     and by using python manage.py migrate command in cmd , i am getting huge error

Comment: mainly I can see from error :                                                                         1.ensure_connection self.connect()                                                                   2.access denied for user'root'@localhost                                                                   and so on ....Is der any issue in database settings for mysql i.e HOST , USER etc or some other issue ? please help me to sort it out